# Error message append only once

Tags: javascript, loops, append

I am trying to append an error message to html once there was no match in the search bar. I have a list and once there is no match the list items get display:none; That's when i want to have the message. The problem is that being inside a loop to iterate through the list this message is appended the same number of times as the number of list items.

Updated code: it seems the error message doesn't appear each time i search for a student that is not a match...unless i refresh the page. Also sometimes even when i have the matching student the error shows although it shouldn't.

```
    //add search bar 
$( ".page-header" ).append('<div class="student-search"></div>');
$( ".student-search" ).append('<input id="input-search" placeholder="Search for students..."/><button id="search">Search</button>');
$('.page').append('<div class="error"></div>'); 
$('.error').append('<p>"Student not found!"</p>');
$('.error').hide(); 
var found = true;



//myFunction
function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input-search");
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("student-list");
    var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) { 
        var h = li[i].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
        if (h.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
            found = true;  
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
            console.log('Hello! Student is not found!');
            found = false;  
            }        
    }
    $('.pagination').hide();
    if (found === false) {
        $('.error').show();
    } 
}
//myFunction end

// when the input is empty return to page 1, empty the error div, show pagination, 

$('#input-search').on('keyup', function() {
 if($(this).val() === '') {
   $('.error').empty();
   go_to_page(0);
   $('.pagination').show();
  }
});


$('#search').click(function(){
      myFunction();
});
```

Thanks,
Alina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a demo for you, I hope it's what you want:
https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/xpdof2jh/14/

First, every time the user makes a search, we need to remove all the previous errors. I added a variable `found` to track if the username matches the filter. I added conditions to show the search results.

Reset the `.error` when the input is empty.

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
 if($(this).val() === '') {
   $('.error').empty()
  }
});
```

Comment: That worked very well! I just added the variable 'found' to my code and the 'if' statement. The only problem I have now is that once I delete my current search and type in another search the error text is appended and added to the page twice. Is there a way to make the error message disappear once the input becomes empty? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, again you are a star! Thank you for your help. It works well but  it has some bugs. It seems that the message appears only if i first search for the not found student, if i first have matching student as result and right after i search again for one that doesnt exist the message doesnt show. Instead even if i search  for the existing students it shows, but it shouldn't. So it only recognises the 'found' being false just once unless i refresh the page. I updated my code in my question, I must be doing something wrong there....:( please help